# Problems with HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Okay, So I'm following a tutorial from W3Schools and Im trying to place this canvas inside a div. Problem is, it keeps going back to the start of body? Ive tried changing some of the code but I just cant get it right! Any chance someone could shed some light? Im trying to put it in a div called "gameCanvas" but ive pasted the code that works.

```
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
myGameArea.start();
}

 var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
},
stop : function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `document.body.childNodes[0]` the div you are trying to wrap the canvas in?

You are currently inserting your canvas before the div (`insertBefore`) instead of inside it. You can use `document.body.childNodes[0].appendChild(this.canvas)` to add the canvas as a child to the div.

**Edit:**

Knowing that the div you are trying to append to has the id `gameCanvas` the following should work:

Replace `document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0])` in your original code with `document.getElementById('gameCanvas').appendChild(this.canvas)`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, though I cant quite seem to get it to work. Im probably being really blonde.. Either way The div Im trying to add it to is called "gameCanvas", the code I posted is from a testing file to see why it wasnt working..

Comment: Are you getting any errors now? Can you try using `document.getElementById('gameCanvas')` instead of `document.body.childNodes[0]`? If it's still not working it would be helpful if you could provide a jsfiddle showcasing the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2t0685ts/ Take a look at that, Its probably something really simple, Im new to JS to dont be too harsh on me!

Comment: Absolute diamond!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for taking the pain, connorrickk and @Bastiaanus